# Fubini's theorem for tempered distributions

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, schwartz-space, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let's say I have a distribution $u\in\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and two function $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{n+m})$, $g\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^m)$.

Then
\begin{align}
\tilde{f}(y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u(x)f(x,y)~dx
\end{align}
should again be a Schwartz function and thus
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^m}g(y)\tilde{f}(y)~dy
\end{align}
is a complex number.

On the other hand, I could first evaluate
\begin{align}
\tilde{g}(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^m}f(x,y)g(y)~dy
\end{align}
and then $u(\tilde{g})$ is a second complex number.

Lastly, $u\otimes g$ defines a unique distribution in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{n+m})$ by the nuclear/Schwartz kernel theorem and $(u\otimes g)(f)$ is a third complex number.

If $u$ were an integrable function, then it is clear that at least the first two numbers are the same due to Fubini's theorem. Is this still true for all tempered distributions? I imagine one could choose some $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $u_n\rightarrow u$ and since Fubini holds for each term of this sequence it should also hold for the limit. Am I right?

What about the third case?

Comment: Haven't you mixed up $f$ and $g$?

Comment: Yes, I fixed it now

Comment: Shouldn't "Lastly, $u\otimes f$ defines a unique distribution in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{n+m})$" be "Lastly, $u\otimes g$ defines a unique distribution in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{n+m})$"?

Comment: There is a Fubini Theorem for distributions, see for example https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72450/can-distribution-theory-be-developed-riemann-free/351028#351028 the easiest way to prove it is to the use the isomorphism with spaces of sequences provided by Hermite functions.

Comment: @md2perpe I corrected this

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Thank you very much for the link.